# Keeping track of socket.io sessions for logging

Tags: node.js, logging, websocket, socket.io

I am working on making a generic logging module for my application and am trying to add session information to each log (requestId/socketId, userId, etc.) But I am running into some issues with logging websockets.

Basically my application has 2 parts: a restAPI (express) and websockets (socket.io)

Both the restAPI and websockets use some of the same functions (database edits etc.), now these functions should log errors or other useful data.

But passing the session information to the logger module will create a lot of overhead and makes the code quite unreadable, so I am looking for a way to save the session information so that the logger can get the information from there.

For the restAPI this was fairly simple using asyncLocalStorage and I was hoping to utilize the same principle for the websockets but I guess its not that simple.

My (partially) working code setup is as follows:

Global context creator (logAsyncContext.ts):

```
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from "async_hooks";

export const context = new AsyncLocalStorage();


export const createContext = (data: any, callBack: () => any) => {
  const store = data;

  return context.run(store, () => callBack());
};
```

This is then used by the middleware of the restAPI and websockets

RestAPI middleware (apiLogContext.ts):

```
// Import the required modules
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

// Import custom utilities
import { createContext } from "../../utils/logAsyncContext";
import { logger } from "../../utils/logger";

// Generate a unique ID for incoming requests and store in context so logger can access it
export const apiLogContext = (
  req: Request,
  _res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const logData = {
    api: {
      requestId: v4(),
      originalUrl: req.originalUrl,
    },
  };

  return createContext(logData, () => debugLog(next));
};

const debugLog = (next: NextFunction) => {
  logger. Debug("API log context created");

  return next();
};
```

websocket middleware (wsLogContext.ts):

```
// Import the required modules
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import { Socket } from "socket.io";

// Import custom utilities
import { createContext } from "../../utils/logAsyncContext";
import { logger } from "../../utils/logger";

// Generate a unique ID for incoming requests and store in context so logger can access it
export const wsLogContext = (socket: Socket, next: () => void) => {
  const logData = {
    ws: {
      socketId: v4(),
      nameSpace: socket.nsp.name,
    },
  };

  return createContext(logData, () => debugLog(next));
};

const debugLog = (next: () => void) => {
  logger.debug(`WS log context created`);

  return next();
};
```

Now the logger can get the context from logAsyncContext.ts:

```
import { context } from "./logAsyncContext";

const getStore = () => {
  // Get the store from the AsyncLocalStorage
  const store = context.getStore();
 
  // If the store is not defined, log an error
  if (!store) {
    console.log("Store is not defined");
    return undefined;
  }

  return store;
};

export function debug(message: string) {
  // Get the context
  const store = getStore();

  if (!store) {
    return;
  }

  if (isAPILog(store)) {
    console.debug(
      `DEBUG LOG: ${store.api.requestId} | ${store.api.originalUrl} - ${message}`
    );
  } else {
    console.debug(
      `DEBUG LOG: ${store.ws.socketId} | ${store.ws.nameSpace} - ${message}`
    );
  }
};
```

This works perfectly for the restAPI but for the websockets its a different story, it does log the initial debug message ("WS log context created") but everything logged after cannot access the store ("Store is not defined")

Now I am sure this is very logical but I don't fully understand the structure of data for websocket connections, so I am asking, am I just making a simple mistake or is this whole setup of logging for websockets incorrect? If so what would be the better way (without needing to pass the session info with every log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @bohdan for reminding me that this issue was still unanswered. While his solution works, I will also explain what I did for anyone wondering how to do this using middleware.

What I learned is that WebSockets can be very confusing but quite logical, for me the most important thing to realize was that you cannot use the "same" asyncLocalStorage for a single socket as long as that socket is connected. So I use a different asyncLocalStorage for each event (I will call them stores)

For me there are 4 different "stores" for a websocket connection Which cannot share the same store.

1. When a connection is made
2. When an event is received (frontend --> backend)
3. When an event is sent (backend --> frontend)
4. When a connection is closed

For all of these types I (mostly) use the same middleware:

```ts
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from "async_hooks";
import { Socket } from "socket.io"
import { v4 } from "uuid";

const context = mew AsyncLocalStorage();

const wsLogStore = (socket: Socket, next: () => void) => {
  const newData: any = {
    // Any data you want to save in the store
    // For example socket Id
    socketId: socket.id
    // I also add an eventId which I can later use in my logging to combine all logs belonging to a single event
    eventId: v4()
  }

  return context.run(newData, () => callBack())
}
```

**#1 For the first type (when a connection is made)**

You can use the middleware like this:

```ts
// Import the middleware we just created
import wsLogStore from "./wsLogStore"

// io = socketIO server instance (io = new Server)
io.use(wsLogStore)
```

Now a store will be available everywhere as long as it happens directly after the connection

**#2 When a event is received (frontend --> backend)**

```ts
io.use((socket, next) => {
  socket.use((event, next) => {
    wsLogStore(socket, () => {
      next()
    });
  });
})
```

Now everywhere you use `socket.on("<any event>")` A store will have been created and usable

**#3 When an event is sent (backend --> frontend)**

Now this one is a little bit different since depending on your implementation this will not be easy, for example when you sent something to a specific room, is it enough to create a single store for the whole room? Or do you want to have a separate one for each socket that is receiving a event? And how do we create a store since we don't have a specific socket available?

For my use case it was absolutely necessary to have a separate store for each socket that is receiving an event.

```ts
const sentEventsToSockets = () => {
  // Get the sockets you want to send a event to,
  // For example, you could get the sockets from a room

  const sockets = (Array.from(io.sockets.values()) as Socket[]).filter((socket) => socket.rooms.has("your room"))
  
  for (const socket of sockets) {
    wsLogStore(socket, () => {
      //Here a separate store for each socket will be available
      socket.emit("your event")
    })
  }
}
```

**#4 When a connection is closed**

Sadly, the store we created in step 1 is not available in this case so we would need to create a new one.

```ts
io.use((socket, next) => {
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    wsLogStore(socket, () => {
      // A separate store will be available here if a connection is closed
    });
  });
})
```

**Conclusion**

While it would be easier if we could create a single store for each socket and use it the whole time, it seems like that is simply not possible.

By saving the socketId in our store we can however combine all data that we need afterwards. For example, in logging.

Note: If you use namespaces the socketId will be different for each namespace, you could use the connection id `socket.conn.id` which is a unique ID for each socket (no matter which namespace). Why this value is marked as private (if using TS) I have no clue

All of this will of course be slightly different depending on your use case and implementation. For example, if you use namespaces then you need to make sure the middleware is applied in each namespace.

I hope someone finds this helpful and if there are any question about how I do things or how to improve my setup, I would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

I faced with same issue.

After shallow investigation, I can suppose following moments:

1. socket.io middlewares are not the same as in express.(not 100% sure)
2. There known issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32330 (closed but with tricky code)

To go forward with AsyncLocalStorage in sockets.io I do next steps:

```
// context.js
const uuid = require('uuid').v4;
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('async_hooks');

const context = new AsyncLocalStorage();
const enterWith = (data) => context.enterWith({traceId: uuid(), ...data });
module.exports = { context, enterWith };


// sockets.js
// I have legacy socket.io v2, your code may be different
io.use(contextMiddleware);
    io.use(authSocket);
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.on('USER_CONNECT', async () => {
            socket.emit('Exo', `USER_CONNECT`);
            try {
// The main solution is here, enter a valid context before actual controller execution
                await enterWith({ userId: socket.chatuser });
                await userService.createOrUpdateChatUser({ userId: socket.chatuser, customerId });
                socket.emit('Exo', `User created`);
            } catch (e) {
                logger.error(`Create user failure ${e.message}`, { error: e });
                socket.emit('Error', e.message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I have found a slightly different solution myself since asking the question as seen in my answer